# How to traverse Neo4j Graph optimally with read-only operations?

Tags: java, multithreading, graph, neo4j, bigdata

I am using Neo4j graph [Java API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/). I have constructed a graph in Neo4J which looks like following-

[image]

I have `Person` node and `Article` node on graph. They are connected with multiple paths via other nodes.

I want to traverse all paths between every `Person` and `Article` node to calculate [Random Walk Probability](https://people.math.osu.edu/husen.1/teaching/571/random_walks.pdf). Problem is graph is huge and I want to use multithreaded approach.

Following would be the pseudocode-

```
function processGraph()
{
  For each personId in personIdList
     For each articleId in articelIdList 
        randomWalkScore = getRandomWalkScore(personId, articleId)
        storeRandomWalkScore(personId, articleId, randomWalkScore)
}

function getRandomWalkScore(personId, articleId)
{
    randomWalkScore = 0
    beginTransaction()
    {
      personNode = findPersonNode(personId)
      articleNode = findArticleNode(articleId)
      paths = findAllPathsBetween(personNode, articleNode)
         For each path in Paths
            randomWalkScore += getRandomWalkScore(path) // This will iterate over each relationship in path and multiply their weights
    } //End Transaction

    return randomWalkScore
}
```

In short, this is a graph traversal and consist of read-only operations.

In Neo4J each [Transaction](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) is thread bound so I run `getRandomWalkScore(..)` function in separate threads. Though it works and utilizes all cores at start but after ~10 hours it uses only 1 or 2 cores. It takes huge amount of memory ~60GB though on disk size of my graph is ~1GB. In addition to that it takes very long time to complete. I have following queries-

1. What is the optimal way of doing this operation on Neo4J graph?
2. How can I reduce memory footprint of this program?
3. How can I reduce the execution time?

Any suggestion or pointer would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since your doing a massive graph global operation you should consider writing your code multithreaded.

Please note that there's a ongoing project focussing on this kind of workload and delivers most common global graph algorithms, see https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/. Is pagerank what you want at the end of the day? If your algo is missing there, please open a github issue there.

Comment: The algorithm I need is little different than page rank. It's basically calculating random walk probability between two nodes. Do you have suggestions on why does these path finding operations taking so much memory and how can it be reduced?

Comment: I suspect the `findAllPathsBetween` will return a huge number of possibilities.